# Beamer overlay with `nicematrix`

Tags: tables, beamer, overlays, nicematrix

I'd like to uncover a table row-by-row in a `NiceTabular` environment (provided by the [`nicematrix`](http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf) package). My table has alternating row colors, and I'd like overlay to cover/uncover the row color *and* its content at the same time. I'd also like to stick to the `nicematrix` package instead of using the conventional `tabular`/`array` environments.

I tried several ways that work in `tabular` and similar environments, but not in `NiceTabular`. These include:

- [Putting `\pause` at the end of a row](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/229995/18228)
- [Using `\onslide` or `\only`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83734/18228)

### MWE

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{.4\textwidth}m{.4\textwidth}}
  \CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{gray!50}{1} % heading
    \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{} % body
  \Body
  \toprule
  \onslide<2->{Head 1 & Head 2} \\
  \midrule
  Row 1 Col 1 & Row 1 Col 2 \pause\\
  Row 2 Col 1 & Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 \\
  \bottomrule 
\end{NiceTabular}

Overlay in conventional \texttt{tabular} for comparison:
\begin{tabular}{m{.4\textwidth}m{.4\textwidth}}
  \toprule
  \onslide<2->{Head 1 & Head 2} \\
  \midrule
  Row 1 Col 1 & Row 1 Col 2 \pause\\
  Row 2 Col 1 & Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 Row 2 Col 2 \\
  \bottomrule 
\end{tabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your MWE is not very clear (at least for me): there is two cells with the content `Row 1 Col 1`. Is it by design?

Comment: @F.Pantigny: Sorry they are just typos from copy-pasting. I'll fix that. BTW, thank you for the excellent package!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I would do.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{.4\textwidth}m{.4\textwidth}}
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
  \rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}
\Body
\toprule
  Head 1 & Head 2 \\
\midrule
\only<2->
  { Row 1 Col 1 & text text text text text text text text text text }
\only<3->
  { \\ Row 2 Col 1 & text text text text text }
\only<4->
  { \\ Row 3 Col 1 & text text text text text text text text text }
\only<5->
  {
    \\ Row 4 Col 1 & text text \\
    \bottomrule
  }
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

As usual with `nicematrix`, you need several compilations.

---

If you accept to write in white the text that must be hidden, you have also the following solution (with a centered vertical position of the tabular).

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\centering
\color{white}
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{.4\textwidth}m{.4\textwidth}}[rules/color=black]
\CodeBefore
  \rowcolor{gray!50}{1}
\Body
\toprule
  \RowStyle[color=black]{}
  Head 1 & Head 2 \\
\midrule
\only<2->{\RowStyle[color=black,rowcolor=gray!25]{}}
  Row 1 Col 1 & text text text text text text text text text text \\ 
\only<3->{\RowStyle[color=black]{}}
  Row 2 Col 1 & text text text text text \\ 
\only<4->{\RowStyle[color=black,rowcolor=gray!25]{}}
  Row 3 Col 1 & text text text text text text text text text \\ 
\only<5->{\RowStyle[color=black]{}}
  Row 4 Col 1 & text text \\
\bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. This is almost what I want. It'd be nice if the table does not need to be top-aligned. Is it possible for `nicematrix` environments to process TikZ styling options such as [`visible on`](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/146991/18228)?

Comment: Is there a reason why you nest the `\only`'s? They seem to work also when issued separately on each row (before the `\\`).

Comment: @HerrK. You are right: there is no point nesting the `\only`. I have changed my answer.

Comment: @HerrK. At this time, I don't see any way to have `visible on` working for rows in `nicematrix`. I will investigate.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'll go with your second solution.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be possible if you use `\onslide` inside of each cell. This might be a lot of code depending on the complexity of your table, though.

I tried the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix,booktabs}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\centering
\begin{NiceTabular}{m{.4\textwidth}m{.4\textwidth}}
  \CodeBefore
    \rowcolor{gray!50}{1} % heading
    \onslide<3->{\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}} % body
  \Body
  \toprule
  Head 1 & Head 2 \\
  \midrule
  \onslide<2->{Row 1 Col 1} & \onslide<2->{Row 1 Col 2} \\
  \onslide<3->{Row 2 Col 1} & \onslide<3->{Row 2 Col 2} \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

... and got the following output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. However, when I compiled your code, I got [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mr4rQ.gif), where the background color of Row 2 didn't get covered.

Comment: Strange. Did you use `\onslide<3->{\rowcolors{2}{gray!25}{}}`?

Comment: Yes, I did. I also made multiple compilations.

Comment: I don't know the reason for this. Sorry, then you should stick to F. Pantigny's solution, I guess.